# Get token from Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

When I log in using Facebook I get a photoURL with better quality like this:

```
...
FacebookAccessToken myToken = facebookUser.accessToken;
if (myToken == null) {
   return false;
}
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(myToken.token);
...
User user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
this.facebookPhotoURL = user.photoURL + "/picture?height=600&access_token=" + myToken.token;
```

This is working fine and I can pass the height that I need but when I refresh the status of the app or I reboot it I'm not performing this login, I just get the user by doing this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

How could I get the token from this or from a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase persists the credentials for Firebase Authentication, so that it can restore it when the app is restarted. It does however not persist the **Facebook** credentials (as it has no need for them after the initial sign-in).

So while you can get the Firebase token from the Firebase SDK, if you want to also get the Facebook access token you will either have to persist that yourself, or make another call to the Facebook SDK.

Comment: I understand that if I save that token it will get invalid at some point right? Or until I have that session saved the same token is used/valid? If so the solution is simple then